# Why do we set Gradle classpath reference in both project's and module's build.gradle?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When we create an empty Android Gradle project using Android Studio 1.1.0 (and all older versions of Android Studio), there are two references to the Gradle plugin. One reference is in the Project's `build.gradle` and another reference is in the module's `build.gradle`. And the both look exactly the same

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.x.x'
    }
}
```

As I experienced, the version of Gradle from project's file is more important because I can set the latest Gradle in it (v 1.1.3. for Android Studio 1.1.0) while I can leave(!) older version of Gradle in the module's `build.gradle`. The project will compile without any errors.

So why is the module's reference there on the first place?

Let's say that the reason is so that we can use other Gradle version in some modules. Does it mean that I can remove these lines of code from module's `build.gradle` if I plan to use the same Gradle version through out the project? This way I have to update the same line in all modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do NOT have to! It seems that this habit was present in the previous versions of Android Studio (probably before the official release).

In Android Studio v1.1.0 there is only one reference - in projet's `build.gradle`.

Note: this project was created on the older version of Android Studio (not sure which one) and inherited its code.